# What would happen if I made a HTTP request to a server without Apache installed?

Tags: apache, http, amazon-web-services

Doesn't have to be Apache, but that's just the only HTTP server I know of (Actually could you guys recommend alternatives that I could look into as well?)

Anyways, so I have been messing around with Amazon Web Services and I created an EC2 server instance with an Amazon Linux Image.  On that, (Following guides and examples) I installed Apache and now when I make a GET request to my public IP, it returns to me the HTML files I created on my server.

My question is, what if I never installed Apache, and then made an HTTP request to my public IP?  For no reason really, the question just came up in my head and I'm curious.  I'd rather not figure out how to uninstall Apache or create a new instance to figure it out, so I was wondering if somebody could weigh in as well as tell me a little more about what it is exactly apache does on a server.  My understanding is that it is a layer you can install on your server OS that will create a socket listener to port 80 (HTTP), and when a request is made on that port, Apache will return web pages?  Also I think I read somewhere you could configure Apache to forward a port to something like a python server script?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> could you guys recommend alternatives that I could look into as well?)

`nginx` is a popular alternative to `apache`. It's much more efficient.

> what if I never installed Apache, and then made an HTTP request to my public IP?

Your browser would get a "connection reset" because there is nothing on port 80. Your browser would display a message (Chrome says "This webpage is not available").  You would *NOT* get a "404" because that requires an HTTP server to send HTTP codes.

If your server was firewalled instead, you'd bet a busy wait for a while, then a message about the server not responding.

> Also I think I read somewhere you could configure Apache to forward a port to something like a python server script?

Yes, that is called "reverse proxy" mode. It's essential to any application website if you want to scale. The web server(s) can distribute traffic to one or more backends running the application.  The web server is useful for filtering bad requests (since your backend in Ruby/Python will be 1000's of times slower than the reverse proxy.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to test what will happen if Apache isn't installed, you can always just stop the Apache service by typing:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

or

```
sudo service httpd stop
```

depending on your version. Then if you visit your site's webpage you'll get a 404 error or something similar.

There are ways to use python scripts to run simple servers, but in general it's easier to just let Apache handle that and use a framework like Ruby on Rails or Django to control the display and creation of content for your server.

Comment: I didn't even think about being able to stop apache haha.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: You can't get a 404: That is a HTTP code and requires a HTTP server to send it.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Just wanted to give an example of an error, didn't think it through.